# Use storybook alongside rollup and a tsconfig using nodenext

Tags: typescript, storybook

My project requires nodenext module resolution to be built. I am using rollup for bundling and tsc for type checking. This means every relative path I import from has to mention a file extension, and because I am using typescript, there is a mismatch between the actual source file extension (`.ts`) and the one I must use in my imports (`.js`)

I can't get that to work with storybook react-webpack5. I get errors such as the following when I import components in my stories:

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../colors.js' in 'E:\path\to\src\components'

The question is how could I configure either TS, rollup or storybook to work together nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typescript 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0#resolution-customization-flags) has this new config option: `allowImportingTsExtensions`. It enables using `.ts` extensions in import paths.

With this in place, storybook has no problem resolving the modules.

`allowImportingTsExtensions` requires that `tsc` does not emit files other than declarations, but since I let rollup do the building it is not an issue.